# How can I sync multiple photo and video folders in iTunes?

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, windows, photos, itunes

I have an iPhone 4, a PC, and iTunes 10. I can't figure out how to sync photos AND videos from multiple folders.

In iTunes' iPhone view, under "Pictures" I can select a single master folder, then subfolders to sync. Eg, I have "D:\Pictures" and I select the "2010" folder. Fine. But I'd also like to sync "D:\Videos" and select its "2010" folder. I see that the "Pictures" option also allows you to sync videos. But what's impossible to do, as far as I can tell, is sync multiple folders arbitrarily located in my folder hierarchy, rather than multiple subfolders of a single parent folder.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess here because I don't sync mine on a windows system. But you can probably use symbolic links to your other folders, within the ones that actually sync.

Here is how to do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363878(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is a programming command. Use **mklink** in a command window to interactively make a link.